# See a list of all pages which link to my site page

Tags: hyperlink

I have multiple site pages in modern SharePoint:

- A.aspx
- B.apsx
- C.aspx
- D.aspx

In A I have recreated quick links to C and D, in B I have created a quick link to C.

Is there a way to add a web part in C that will show me that A and B are linked to it?